# msbuild post build task not copying files

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core

I have a c# project where I am trying to copy some configuration json files to my build out put directory

the config currently looks like this

```
   <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
        <ItemGroup>
            <PluginAssembly Include="$(SolutionDir)\Cli\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\**\Cli.dll" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(PluginAssembly)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
        <ItemGroup>
            <IocComponents Include="$(SolutionDir)\Node\Settings\Templates\components.json" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(IocComponents)" DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)\Cli\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\**\components.json" />
    </Target>
```

My PluginAssembly rules work fine copy over the dll to the correct folders but copying the json doesnt do anything?

Im new to c# so forgive me if its something simple!

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="..\Node\Settings\Templates\components.json;..\Node\Settings\Templates\config.devnet.json;..\Node\Settings\Templates\config.testnet.json;..\Node\Settings\Templates\config.mainnet.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot include these files in your project and set the CopyToOutputDirectcory to ture in Visual Studio?

Comment: im using rider but  i am trying the CopyToOutputDirectory and CopyToPublishDirectory rules which dont seem to copy it, I have updated my questions with the setting i am trying

Comment: why are you using a wildcard (`**`) in `DestinationFolder`? this parameter is supposed to be set to a single folder name

Comment: As well as what Martin said, the ItemGroup None is incorrectly defined.  It should be an Include attribute and not an Update attribute.